# mySQL - Separate Lastname,Firstname and CompanyName entries from a single column

Tags: mysql, select, substring

I've got a column in a database which contains company names, and customer names... what I'd *like* to do is keep the CompanyName column completely intact, but wherever there is a comma in the CompanyName I'd like to take that information and populate it into a FirstName and LastName field. So that basically...

(each number represents a different row in the table)

Before:

**CompanyName Column:**
1. Big Company Inc
2. Smith, John
3. Sue, Maggie

After:

**CompanyName Column:**
1. Big Company Inc
2. Smith, John
3. Sue, Maggie

**LastName Column:**
1.
2. Smith
3. Sue

**FirstName Column:**
1.
2. John
3. Maggie

This one is pretty dang tricky for me... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have these values separator?

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing. The values in the quotes are on separate rows and all have an numerical key as well if those help.

Comment: I mean the values in CompanyName field. Have they any separator or they are just quoted?

Comment: sorry the quotes are just here for example... let me update the main post. im probly not making sense...

Comment: So there are some comma's in the records that identify when its a persons name, and it goes lastname, firstname in each record that that is the case

Comment: My question still remains. If you don't have any separator you can't separate these values.

Comment: Are these values different rows?

Comment: Yes they're in different rows

Comment: Not wise solution :). But if you have everytime 3 rows per record (Company) you can get tehm 3 by 3, and then do whatever you want with them

Comment: ohhh sorry they're not in different rows... sorry they're in completely separate records. They're basically Company names intermingled with individuals names. I'd like to have where a record is a persons name the name extracted and placed into LastName and FirstName columns, while still preserving the CompanyName record as is.

Comment: I updated the main post again, perhaps it'll make a little more sense. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hm. I don't think it can be done with one query. May be stored procedure that checks for comma in the value and then separate the value and insert it in other tables

Comment: splitting values can be done using SUBSTRING_INDEX

Comment: Yea - unfortunately it's a little far outside my scope of skill/experience. I'll keep plugging away and I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id, companyName, if(companyName like '%,%', substring_index(companyname, ',', -1), '') firstName, 
       if(companyName like '%,%', substring_index(companyname, ',', 1), '') lastName
from company;
```

Comment: Works - Used this to populate the two other columns - many thanks!